# Feeding newdata to R predict function

Tags: r

R's `predict` function can take a `newdata` parameter and its document reads:

> newdata An optional data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict. If omitted, the fitted values are used.

But I found that it is not totally true depending on how the model is fit. For instance, following code works as expected:

```
x <- rnorm(200, sd=10)
y <- x + rnorm(200, sd=1)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
train = sample(1:length(x), size=length(x)/2, replace=F)
dataTrain <- data[train,]
dataTest <- data[-train,]
m <- lm(y ~ x, data=dataTrain)
head(predict(m,type="response"))
head(predict(m,newdata=dataTest,type="response"))
```

But if the model is fit as such:

```
m2 <- lm(dataTrain$y ~ dataTrain$x)
head(predict(m2,type="response"))
head(predict(m2,newdata=dataTest,type="response"))
```

The last two line will produce exactly the same result. The `predict` function works in a way ignoring `newdata` parameter, i.e. it can't really compute the prediction on new data at all.

The culprit, of course, is `lm(y ~ x, data=dataTrain)` versus `lm(dataTrain$y ~ dataTrain$x)`. But I didn't find any document that mentioned the difference between these two. Is it a known issue?

I'm using R 2.15.2.

Comment: Hi I am having the same problem, have you by any chance figure out a way to solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See `?predict.lm` and the Note section, which I quote below:

```
Note:

     Variables are first looked for in ‘newdata’ and then searched for
     in the usual way (which will include the environment of the
     formula used in the fit).  A warning will be given if the
     variables found are not of the same length as those in ‘newdata’
     if it was supplied.
```

Whilst it doesn't state the behaviour in terms of "same name" etc, as far as the formula is concerned the terms you passed in to it were of the form `foo$var` and there are no such variables with names like that either in `newdata` or along the search path that R will traverse to look for them.

In your second case, you are totally misusing the model formula notation; the idea is to succinctly and symbolically describe the model. Succinctness and repeating the data object *ad nauseum* are not compatible.

The behaviour you note is **exactly** consistent with the documented behaviour. In simple terms, you fitted the model with terms `data$x` and `data$y` then tried to predict for terms `x` and `y`. As far as R is concerned those are different names and hence different things and it did right to not match them.

Comment: I take that it means 'you fitted the model with terms data$x and data$y then tried to predict for terms x and y'. But I see your point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @edwardw yes, sorry. Fixed now.

Comment: At the risk of getting downvotes: let's face it, the manual is less than intuitive on this subject. For instance, if you pass a model in terms of data frame columns, like in `lm(mydata$y ~ mydata$x,...)` then be prepared for all sorts of surprises when you want to pass `mydata=` to `predict()`. Should the column be called `x`? `mydata$x`? Something else?... :-) I did not figure it out, just copied the columns to standalone `x` and `y` vectors, and after reading this excellent explanation I could use `predict(model,mydata=data.frame(x=whatever),...)`.