# stargazer R: Display mulitple regression with different data next to each other

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I´m wirting on my bachelor´s thesis and have a problem with the stragazer function in R.
Basic question: What drives unemployment? Therefore I ran a logit-regression to estimate what factors raise the probability to get unemployed. I have 7 different data frames of 7 different years, so I run 7 different logit regressions with the same dependent (and independent) variables. (In this case its only the effect of age i´m interested in.

```
logit17 <- glm(formula = data17$AL ~  data17$age,
          family = "binomial", data = data17)
logit16 <- glm(formula = dataP_16$AL ~  dataP_16$age,
          family = "binomial", data = data16)
```

So far so easy. The problem I am facing now: 
When running the regressions through stargazer, the out output looks like the following:

[image: stargazer output]

Apparently stargazer recognizes age as two different variables (which they kinda are, because it´s a different data set). In addtion, when I insert more variables and the regressions of the other years the table gets extremly long.

My question: Is there any function to avoid these huge tables? I guess I somehow need to tell stargazer that it should treat age and the other variable as one.
Thanks

Comment: The modeling function code should be: `glm(formula = AL ~  age, family = "binomial", data = data17)`. In other words, don't restate the data frame name in the formula. It's not necessary to do so, because you passed the data frame to the `glm` function with the `data` argument, and it can have undesirable effects, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115909/feeding-newdata-to-r-predict-function).

Comment: thanks a lot - this solves my problem!